# How to match file extensions regardless of case in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

Let's just say i want to match the `.abc` extension but it could come over as `.ABC` or `.AbC`. How can I identify all of these variations of the `.abc` extension in order to process `.abc` files?

Right now i'm using:

`ls | grep -i .abc`

but i've heard that piping to grep is usually not the best idea. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Can you put that command in context?

Comment: I have a process that takes one zip file. The zip file contains a .abc file that i'd like to have a handle on and process but, in the past i've been burned on not catching funky variations of a file extension. So i'm trying to make sure that my script will ALWAYS identify the .abc file no matter how the extension looks.

Answer (score 4):

If you enter the extension literally, you can use character classes:

```
ls *.[Aa][Bb][Cc]
```

You can also use the `-iname` option of `find`:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.abc'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `nocaseglob` option to the `shopt` builtin to make globs not pay attention to case.

```
$ touch foo.abc foo.ABC
$ echo *.abc
foo.abc
$ shopt -s nocaseglob
$ echo *.abc
foo.ABC foo.abc
```